# Applying for b1 visa before starting employment

Tags: visa, usa, business

1) I have recently left my employer to take up a job with another company. I have another 3 weeks to go before joining the new employer.

However the new employer wants me to process my B1 visa so that I can travel to USA in the 1st week of joining to attend a 2 week training. This means I will have to attend the visa interview before I joining the new employer. Will this cause issues in the interview?

2) Also since I have not joined the new company yet, I do not have any payslips to show the visa officer. What can I do to fix this problem?

3) Finally, since I am technically between jobs, which company should I list as my current employer in the DS-160 form.

Please advice me on this.

Comment: This is confusing. Are you working for a company that is based in the USA? Will you be working mainly in the USA? Or are you hired by a company that is based or has a branch outside the USA (and you’ll get the paychecks in that other country) but are coming to the USA for a training session?